# Drawimage Unexpected token "." nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, drawimage

i am trying to draw a image but i don't know why this ain't working. I create a new image object then i add the the link of the image to the image object.

but it gives the following error Unexpected token .

```
 this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)';
 this.ctx.fillText('Summoner: '+player2, 10 , 465);
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = 'http://localhost:4004/public/images/Chainlinks/Add%20Burn.png';
 this.ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
```

I edited my post cause now i have another problem the link in src gives the error 304. So thats someting like not found or something. when i type the whole link in the browser it shows the image. so it is linked to right location

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1):

Remove `var` in

```
var img.src = '/public/images/Chainlinks/Add%20Burn.png';
```

You're not declaring a new variable but just setting the `src` property of `img`.

---

For the second question (which should really be in another QA...), it looks like you're facing [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You can't manipulate in JS in a browser the content of an image loaded from another origin if you don't set the relevant CORS headers.

Comment: maybe you can help me with the next problem aswell i edited my question